# Joint moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How to prove that if joint moment generating functions of $n$  random variables is equal to the product of each of their moment generating functions then the random variables are independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(X,Y)$ be random variables such that
$$
M_{(X,Y)}(t,s)=M_X(t)\cdot M_Y(s),\quad s,t\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Let $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$ be an independent copy of $(X,Y)$, i.e. $(X,Y)\sim (\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$ and $(X,Y)\perp\!\!\perp (\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$. In particular we have that

- $X\perp\!\!\perp \tilde{Y}$
- $Y\sim\tilde{Y}$

Then
$$
M_{(X,\tilde{Y})}(t,s)=M_X(t)\cdot M_{\tilde{Y}}(s)=M_X(t)\cdot M_Y(s)=M_{(X,Y)}(t,s),
$$
where we have used that $X\perp\!\!\perp \tilde{Y}$. Since the moment-generating function determines the distribution, we have that $(X,\tilde{Y})\sim (X,Y)$ and hence
$$
\begin{align}
P(X\in A,Y\in B)&=P((X,Y)\in A\times B)=P((X,\tilde{Y})\in A\times B)\\
&=P(X\in A,\tilde{Y}\in B)=P(X\in A)P(\tilde{Y}\in B)\\
&=P(X\in A,Y\in B),
\end{align}
$$
for $A,B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Thus $X\perp\!\!\perp Y$. Now generalize this to $n$ random variables.

Comment: should not you prove that such an independent copy exists ?

Comment: I have understood the solution. But, can you give some intuition on it ? I have never seen this kind of proof technique (I am new to probability).